# Using ls -f to filter files output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to check if a file is a valid file.
Here's the code I'm using.

```
echo "Select your file"
read $TEST_FILE

for file in `ls $TEST_FILE`; do
    if [ -f $TEST_FILE ]; then
        echo "$TEST_FILE is a regular file" 
    fi
done
```

But the results I am getting is this.

```
 is a regular file
 is a regular file
 is a regular file
 is a regular file
 is a regular file
```

It is listing down all the files in the directory when I only specified a specific file. I want it to be able to spit out a result just for that 1 file..

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use that `for` loop?

Comment: Originally, I wanted to list down all the files in a Directory first. If I remove the for loop, then how do I place the ls -f into the if statement?

Answer (score 4):

First, you're using the variable incorrectly with `read`- do not use `$` - you only use `$` when *referring to a variable's existing value*, not when *assigning* a value; instead:

```
echo "Select your file"
read TEST_FILE
```

If the assumption is that `$TEST_FILE` is a single, literal filename, then you don't need the `for` loop at all:

```
if [[ -f $TEST_FILE ]]; then
    echo "$TEST_FILE is a regular file" 
fi
```

If the assumption is that `$TEST` is a filename *pattern*, to the following:

```
for f in $TEST_FILE; do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
        echo "$f is a regular file" 
    fi
done
```

Note that I'm using the more robust and flexible `[[...]]` rather than the `[...]` construct for the tests.

**Afterthought**

The OP mentions the `-f` flag for `ls`, which results in (potentially, depending on the filesystem) *unsorted* output that also *includes entries starting with `.`*

By contrast, the `for` loop with a glob (filename pattern) always expands to *sorted* entries (as far as I've observed).
Also, to make globs match entries that start with `.`, the `dotglob` shell option must be set (`shopt -s dotglob`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the $ after the read. With the code you gave for both, it's not spitting out the echo.. It's just ending the script when I insert an absolute path to be read..

Comment: @user233699: You're welcome; please also see the afterthought I just added. If my answer _solved_ your problem, please click the check mark next to it; if it at least contained _helpful information_, click the up-arrow to up-vote it. This will help others find useful information more quickly (and increase my reputation).

Comment: To add a "why" element to this fine answer, note that `read $TEST_FILE` would expand `TEST_FILE` and use the value as the name of the variable to set. Since `TEST_FILE` is not set, there is no argument to `read`, so the default variable `REPLY` is used. Since `TEST_FILE` itself continues to be unset, the loop iterates over the output of `ls`, which would be every file in the current directory, accounting for the multiple lines of output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want check for just one file, below should work:

```
test -f <the-file-path> && echo "regular file"
```

If you want to check for the regular files in a directory, you should follow the below:

```
echo "Select your file"
read TEST_FILE

for fil in `ls $TEST_FILE`; do
    if [ -f $TEST_FILE/$fil ]; then
        echo "$TEST_FILE/$fil is a regular file" 
    fi
done
```